# NetSuite Advanced PDF/HTML Templates for Item > Group/Kit/Assembly

Tags: netsuite

Is it possible to create an Advanced PDF/HTML Template for Group/Kit/Assembly? This would be the subtype 'Group/Kit/Assembly' located under the type 'Item'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible. Create a saved search filtering item with type only 'kit/package' and use this saved search in your template. if you need more filtering, play with the saved search criteria.